# how to decode quoted-printable using java

Tags: java, encoding

How do I decode quoted-printable using Java. I am reading mail from the server and fetching some data from mail using regex. My mail content type is `text/html` and because of this, I am getting HTML tags along with the data, making it very difficult for me to do the pattern matching. It is showing some characters like `=20`, `=cF`,  etc.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: [MimeUtility](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html) supports quoted-printable. See the [decode()](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decode%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Comment: i have done the same thing.. but it is not decoding...
MimeUtility.decode("String","UTF-8");

Tell me one thing what should i write to decode "quoted-printable" in encoding string????

Comment: First of all, the first parameter to `decode` is an `InputStream`, so your example should not compile.  Second, the second parameter should be `"quoted-printable"`, as it says right in the documentation I linked to.

Comment: @danben You should post that as a proper answer as it solves the problem perfectly!