# How to decode quotable chars (from quotable to a char)?

Tags: java, encoding

I have a text with [quoted-printables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable). Here is an example of such a text (from a [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)):

> If you believe that truth=3Dbeauty, then surely=20=
>   mathematics is the most beautiful branch of philosophy.

I am looking for a Java class, which decode the encoded form to chars, e.g., *=20* to a space.

UPDATE: Thanks to The Elite Gentleman, I know that I need to use QuotedPrintableCodec:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec;
import org.junit.Test;

public class QuotedPrintableCodecTest { 
private static final String TXT =  "If you believe that truth=3Dbeauty, then surely=20=mathematics is the most beautiful branch of philosophy.";

    @Test
    public void processSimpleText() throws DecoderException
    {
        QuotedPrintableCodec.decodeQuotedPrintable( TXT.getBytes() );           
    }
}
```

However I keep getting the following exception:

```
org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException: Invalid URL encoding: not a valid digit (radix 16): 109
    at org.apache.commons.codec.net.Utils.digit16(Utils.java:44)
    at org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec.decodeQuotedPrintable(QuotedPrintableCodec.java:186)
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE 2: I have found [this question @ SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850975/how-to-decode-quoted-printable-using-java) and learn about [MimeUtility](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html):

```
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility;

public class QuotedPrintableCodecTest {
    private static final String TXT =  "If you believe that truth=3Dbeauty, then surely=20= mathematics is the most beautiful branch of philosophy.";

    @Test
    public void processSimpleText() throws MessagingException, IOException  
    {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(TXT.getBytes());

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader(  MimeUtility.decode(is, "quoted-printable") ));         
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); 

            String line;
            while( (line = br.readLine() ) != null )
            {
                writer.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println("INPUT:  "  + TXT);
            System.out.println("OUTPUT: " +  writer.toString() );       
    }
    }
```

However the output still is not perfect, it contains '=' :

```
INPUT:  If you believe that truth=3Dbeauty, then surely=20= mathematics is the most beautiful branch of philosophy.
OUTPUT: If you believe that truth=beauty, then surely = mathematics is the most beautiful branch of philosophy.
```

Now what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) [QuotedPrintableCodec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/QuotedPrintableCodec.html) class does is the implementation of the RFC 1521 Quoted-Printable section.

---

Update, Your quoted-printable string is wrong, as the example on Wikipedia uses Soft-line breaks.

Soft-line breaks:

```
Rule #5 (Soft Line Breaks): The Quoted-Printable encoding REQUIRES
      that encoded lines be no more than 76 characters long. If longer
      lines are to be encoded with the Quoted-Printable encoding, 'soft'
      line breaks must be used. An equal sign as the last character on a
      encoded line indicates such a non-significant ('soft') line break
      in the encoded text. Thus if the "raw" form of the line is a
      single unencoded line that says:

          Now's the time for all folk to come to the aid of
          their country.

      This can be represented, in the Quoted-Printable encoding, as

          Now's the time =
          for all folk to come=
           to the aid of their country.

      This provides a mechanism with which long lines are encoded in
      such a way as to be restored by the user agent.  The 76 character
      limit does not count the trailing CRLF, but counts all other
      characters, including any equal signs.
```

So your text should be made as follows:

```
private static final String CRLF = "\r\n";
private static final String S = "If you believe that truth=3Dbeauty, then surely=20=" + CRLF + "mathematics is the most beautiful branch of philosophy.";
```

The Javadoc clearly states:

> Rules #3, #4, and #5 of the quoted-printable spec are not implemented
>   yet because the complete quoted-printable spec does not lend itself
>   well into the byte[] oriented codec framework. Complete the codec once
>   the steamable codec framework is ready. The motivation behind
>   providing the codec in a partial form is that it can already come in
>   handy for those applications that do not require quoted-printable line
>   formatting (rules #3, #4, #5), for instance Q codec.

And there is a [bug logged](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CODEC-121) for Apache QuotedPrintableCodec as it doesn't support the soft-line breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I get an exception when I try to decode the example from Wikipedia page.

Comment: @Skarab, unless you show us the code & exception stack trace, you can't assume my answer is bad because it threw an exception. You asked for a class that decode quotable characters & I did show you that.

Comment: @Skarab, I updated my post to your homework exercise. I should expect a +1 now :)