# Decoding a "quoted-printable" string in Java

Tags: java, decode, quoted-printable

I would like to use javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility to decode a `"quoted-printable"` string. I do not need any other interface to a mail server. What's the best way to get at that class (and its dependencies)? Alternatively, is there a better way to parse `"quoted-printable"` strings?

Comment: Not sure why this deserved a -2 without commment; it seems like a natural follow-on to an answer to another [question on "quoted-printable" encodings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306432/how-to-decode-quotable-chars-from-quotable-to-a-char).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything in the standard J2SE API for this. However, a quick Google search turns up [this decoder code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Date-Type/Amethodtodecodeencodequotedprintableencodeddata.htm). I can't vouch for it, but it looks reasonable. You can probably find others yourself.

Comment: As it turns out, the code is not quite right... It doesn't seem to increment `retlen` correctly, and thus fails to compute the correct length for most test strings.

Comment: @GeneGolovchinsky - It's good to know that that code has problems. Were you able to fix it or find something else that works?

Comment: Yeah, there is a spurious ‘else‘ due to commented-out code near the end of the main ‘decode‘ method. It prevents the next character from being copied and the buffer index from imcrementing.

Answer (score 6):

The [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) library also has support for [quoted printable](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/net/QuotedPrintableCodec.html) and is available under the more permissive apache license.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Apache Commons Codec to be quite restrictive. It failed to decode a mail in `quoted-printable` format. The option I went with is [MimeUtility#decode](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decode-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-).

Example:

```kotlin
String(MimeUtility.decode(content.byteInputStream(), "quoted-printable").readAllBytes())
```

Comment: Awesome! And no additional dependency required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following simple function im my Android App. It basically looks for equal signs and converts the following two hex digits into one byte, then replacing this 3 chars with the new byte.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class QuotedPrintable {

    static String ASCII_CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 ";

    @SuppressWarnings("CharsetObjectCanBeUsed")
    static String decode(String str) {
        ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char currentChar = str.charAt(i);
            try {
                if(currentChar == '=' && i+2 <= str.length()-1) {
                    char nextChar1 = str.charAt(i+1);
                    char nextChar2 = str.charAt(i+2);
                    int val = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(nextChar1)+String.valueOf(nextChar2), 16);
                    bytes.add((byte) val);
                    i += 2;
                    continue;
                }
            } catch(Exception ignored) {}
            bytes.add((byte) currentChar);
        }
        try {
            return new String(toByteArray(bytes), "UTF-8");
        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ignored) {
            return str;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("CharsetObjectCanBeUsed")
    static String encode(String str) {
        StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            for(String s : splitToCodePoints(str)) {
                if(ASCII_CHARS.contains(s)) {
                    // append standard ASCII chars directly (should be human readable)
                    encoded.append(s);
                } else {
                    // append all bytes of char quoted-printable encoded
                    for(byte b : s.getBytes("UTF-8")) {
                        encoded.append("=").append(String.format("%02X", b));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ignored) {}
        return encoded.toString();
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> splitToCodePoints(String str) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;
        while(count < str.length()) {
            int cp = str.codePointAt(count);
            list.add(new String(Character.toChars(cp)));
            count += Character.charCount(cp);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static byte[] toByteArray(ArrayList<Byte> in) {
        final int n = in.size();
        byte[] ret = new byte[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ret[i] = in.get(i);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    static boolean isVcfFieldQuotedPrintableEncoded(String[] fieldOptions) {
        for(String option : fieldOptions) {
            if(option.toUpperCase().equals("ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Originally posted here: https://gist.github.com/schorschii/c970bfde307a29b2840bd8fe694599c2