# Character-encoding not preserved when dealing with InputStreamReader even after using UTF8

Tags: java, character-encoding

There are data :

```
batiment:Kube D
etage:4ème
description:some_description
```

I want to get these data through InputStreamReader stuff :

```
SharedByteArrayInputStream sbais = (SharedByteArrayInputStream) content;
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(sbais, Charset.forName("UTF8"));
int size = sbais.available();
char[] theChars = new char[size];
int data = reader.read();
int i = 0;
while (data != -1) {
    theChars[i] = (char) data;
    i++;
    data = reader.read();  
}
String parse = new String(theChars);
String[] parties = parse.split("Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable");
String partie = (parties[1]).trim();
parties = partie.split("\\R");
String ret = "";
for(String ligne : parties) {
   if (ligne == null || ligne.trim().equals(""))
        break;
   ret = ret.concat(ligne).concat(System.lineSeparator());
}
return ret;
```

At runtime the data `4ème` is transformed to `4=E8me`

So what is wrong ?

**edit :**

here is the headers of the content :

```
--_008_DB6P190MB0166B6F4DE5E31397B4A7B558C3C9DB6P190MB0166EURP_
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_DB6P190MB0166B6F4DE5E31397B4A7B558C3C9DB6P190MB0166EURP_"

--_000_DB6P190MB0166B6F4DE5E31397B4A7B558C3C9DB6P190MB0166EURP_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

batiment:KUBE D
etage:4=E8me
description:andrana

Cordialement,

...
```

Comment: I am using java 8

Comment: `4=E8me` is the quoted-printable encoding of `4ème`. I.e. your data is encoded for transfer and you need to decode it.

Comment: I get the input from `javax.mail.Message` content ( `getContent()` )

Comment: @JoachimSauer how to decode it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can see that you ignore everything in your content before the String `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`.

That means that your initial content is actually `4=E8me`, which correspond to an ISO-8859-1 string, encoded with [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable).

If you want to transform it to `4ème`, you have to decode it.

There is nothing out of the box for this, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133201/decoding-a-quoted-printable-string-in-java) answer will give you some ideas of library you can use.

For example using [Apache Common Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/), it would be something like:

```
    partie = new QuotedPrintableCodec(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).decode(partie);
```

Comment: I use the Apache Common Codec but I got exception `Invalid URL encoding: not a valid digit (radix 16): 34`

Comment: It depends on the content of your input String. In the content, you should find headers which describe the encoding. Something like `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-15
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable`

Comment: and what should I do when I find the headers ?

Comment: Add them to your question. It is difficult to help you because we don't know how your String is encoded, or even if it is correctly encoded. To get a good answer, we need to have the content of the variable `parse` from your sample.

Comment: ok, I edited the post to include the header before the data I want to retrieve.

Comment: Ok, I found the right place to put the decoding :) , tyvm

Answer (score 0):

After following Obourgain's answer here is the working code :

```
SharedByteArrayInputStream sbais = (SharedByteArrayInputStream) content;
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(sbais, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
int size = sbais.available();
char[] theChars = new char[size];
int data = reader.read();
int i = 0;
while (data != -1) {
    theChars[i] = (char) data;
    i++;
    data = reader.read();  
}
String parse = new String(theChars);
String[] parties = parse.split("Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable");
String partie = (parties[1]).trim();
String[] lignes = partie.split("\\R");
String ret = "";
for(String ligne : lignes) {
     if (ligne == null || ligne.trim().equals(""))
        break;
     String tmp = new QuotedPrintableCodec(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1).decode(ligne, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
     ret = ret.concat(tmp).concat(System.lineSeparator());
}
return ret;
```